# Sorting a list in .Net by one field, then another

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have list of objects I need to sort based on some of their properties. This works fine to sort it by one field:

```
reportDataRows.Sort((x, y) => x["Comment1"].CompareTo(y["Comment1"]));
foreach (var row in reportDataRows) {
   ...
}
```

I see lots of examples on here that do this with only one field. But how do I sort by one field, then another? Or how about a list of many fields? It seems like using LINQ orderby thenby would be best, but I don't know enough about it to know how use it.

For the parameters, something like this that supports any number of fields to sort by would be nice:

```
var sortBy = new List<string>(){"Comment1","Time"};
```

I don't want to be writing code to do this in every one of my apps. I plan on moving this sort code to the class that holds the data so that it can do more advanced things like using a list of parameters and implicitly recognizing that the field is a date and sorting it as a date instead of a string. The reportDataRow object contains fields with this information, so I don't have to do any messy checks to find out if the field is supposed to be a date.

Comment: perhaps you should consider making this a list of the actual object type, either the `reportDataRow`, or creating a new, normal, C# class (POCO) with the properties you desire.  Even better is to use an ORM like LinqToSql or the entity framework.  Once you have a list of objects with properties typed properly (string properties, DaetTime properties, etc.) it is trivial to use LINQ `OrderBy` and most people consider the readability offerred by just using LINQ inline to be preferable to trying to abstract that stuff away.

Comment: I got it to work exactly how I intended, but thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I think it makes more sense to use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
foreach (var row in reportDataRows.OrderBy(x => x["Comment1"]).ThenBy(x => x["Comment2"]) 
{
    ...
}
```

This assumes the other thing you want to order by is "Comment2".

Comment: This does not sort the list, it returns a new sorter IEnumrable

Comment: @Albin, yes, I know that.  But, if you look at the OP's sample, it will work just fine.  The `foreach` will operate on the enumeration sorted precisely as the OP desires.

Comment: foreach (var row in reportDataRows.OrderBy(x => x["Comment1"]).ThenBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x["Time"]))) {

This does exactly what I need it to do, but I don't want to do it here, I want do do it implicitly in the object. I can probably figure it out though, but I'll update this as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
reportDataRows.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    var compare = x["Comment1"].CompareTo(y["Comment1"]);
    if(compare != 0)
        return compare;

    return x["Comment2"].CompareTo(y["Comment2"]);
});
```

Comment: This is the way I used to do it, except with a regular function instead of a lambda. I don't want to write code that works only for sorting one way.

Comment: I personally prefer Linq, but if you don't know regular expressions or Linq, you can sort anything easily like this.

Comment: +1 for actually sorting the list instead of returning another sorted collection

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784833/linq-handling-variable-number-of-orderby/4785149#4785149) where I posted an extension method which handles multiple order by's in LINQ. This allows this sort of syntax:

```
myList.OrderByMany(x => x.Field1, x => x.Field2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example for [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) on msdn.

Comment: @Albin - the same pointless comment on 2 correct responses. Have a better idea? post it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're comparing your own objects, then you can implement the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface.
Otherwise, you can use the [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 0):

You got it. Enumerable.OrderBy().ThenBy() is your ticket. It works exactly like it looks; elements are sorted by each projection, with ties decided by comparing the next projection. You can chain as many ThenBys as you want, and there are also OrderByDesc and ThenByDesc methods that will sort that projection in descending order.

As Albin has pointed out, An OrderBy chain does not touch the original list unless you assign the result of the ordering back to the original variable, like this:

```
reportDataRows = reportDataRows.OrderBy(x=>x.Comment1).ThenBy(x=>x.Comment2).ToList();
```

As a rule, OrderBy will perform slightly slower than List.Sort(); the algorithm is designed to work on any IEnumerable series of elements, so in order to sort (which requires knowing every element of the series) it slurps its entire source enumerable into a new array. However, OrderBy has a distinct advantage over Sort in that it is a "stable" sort; elements that are exactly equal to each other will retain their "relative order" in the sorted enumerable (the first of the two that you;d encounter when iterating through the unsorted list will be the first of the two encountered when iterating through the sorted list).

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ method syntax:

```
var sortedRows = reportDataRows.OrderBy(r => r["Comment1"])
                   .ThenBy(r => r["AnotherField"];

foreach (var row in sortedRows) {
   ...
}
```

And even more readable using query comprehension syntax:

```
var sortedRows = from r in reportDataRows
                 orderby r["Comment1"], r["Comment2"]
                 select r;
foreach (var row in sortedRows) {
   ...
}
```